# fully justified add blank page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm using Harvard style on Sharelatex. In order to fully justify I just added at the header

```
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
```

and once `\justify` at the beginning of the document. It adds a blank page of the pdf numbered with one and then it start counting from the cover page again. If i change `\justify` it add blank page where I insert it.

Comment: I don't understand the question. LaTeX documents are, by default, "fully justified", and using `harvard.sty`, which is a package dealing with bibliographies, should make no difference. So you don't need `ragged2e`. Could you post a MWE consisting of a *complete* minimal document and better explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: the original style doesn't justify the text. So I addded the two line to make it justify. it is justified right now but with this added new blank page. what should post here exactly ?

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: \documentclass{harvard-thesis} which is in the style file uses this \LoadClass[12pt, oneside, letterpaper]{book}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you are using the "Harvard phd" class from Sharelatex, which loads something called `harvard-thesis.cls`, which is not a standard class or part of TeXlive. The offending line is at line 47 of this class, where it issues the command `\raggedright`.

You can either delete this line (better rename the class), or use `\usepackage{ragged2e}` (no need for `document`) and `\justifying` (not justify), which you can give in the preamble after loading the class file. The blank page is not to the result of that, but probably of some `\include` file, if I had to guess.

Personally, I have my doubts about this "template", not least because it seems to make available a lot of fonts which I rather doubt it has a licence for. (As it happens, I do have a licence for those fonts, but they are not freely available.)

Comment: that worked perfectly, thanks a lot. could you just help me again because I can't find where they mention the font type and font size? I have the feeling that the font is smaller than usual even with section and subsection size

Comment: I don't think the fontsizes are being changed, but it uses a font (Arno) that runs quite small. That's the point I'm doubtful about: Arno is not a free font, and unless Sharelatex has a font licence that entitles them to distribute it, it's wrong of them to do so.

Comment: is it possible to change it times news or callibri ?

Comment: Easy enough. You can just delete all the font stuff and, say, `\usepackage{mathptmx}` (which will get you Times). If you are having trouble better to ask a new question.